# Prolog List Merge Question?

Tags: list, merge, prolog

How can merge two list like this?

```
[a,b,c] 

[1,2,3]
```

and I want to make this list

```
[a=1,b=2,c=3].
```

How can I do this? (I use swi prolog)

```
Thanks for your answers. I have a question about it. I write

start:- consult('tennis.pl'),
            see('tennis.pl'),
            repeat,
            read(A),
            A=..List,
            (A\=end_of_file->
            (A\=end_of_file,member('attributes',List)->
            delete(List,'attributes',NewList2);true),
            (A\=end_of_file,member('data',List)->
            delete(List,'data',NewList);true),
            merge(NewList2,NewList,Try),
            write(Try),nl;true),
            A=end_of_file,!,

            seen.


[outlook=_G40,temperature=_G49,humidity=_G58,wind=_G67,play_tennis=_G76]
[_G40=sunny,_G49=hot,_G58=high,_G67=weak,_G76=no]
[_G40=sunny,_G49=hot,_G58=high,_G67=strong,_G76=no]
[_G40=overcast,_G49=hot,_G58=high,_G67=weak,_G76=yes]
[_G40=rain,_G49=mild,_G58=high,_G67=weak,_G76=yes]
[_G40=rain,_G49=cool,_G58=normal,_G67=weak,_G76=yes]
[_G40=rain,_G49=cool,_G58=normal,_G67=strong,_G76=no]
[_G40=overcast,_G49=cool,_G58=normal,_G67=strong,_G76=yes]
[_G40=sunny,_G49=mild,_G58=high,_G67=weak,_G76=no]
[_G40=sunny,_G49=cool,_G58=normal,_G67=weak,_G76=yes]
[_G40=rain,_G49=mild,_G58=normal,_G67=weak,_G76=yes]
[_G40=sunny,_G49=mild,_G58=normal,_G67=strong,_G76=yes]
[_G40=overcast,_G49=mild,_G58=high,_G67=strong,_G76=yes]
[_G40=overcast,_G49=hot,_G58=normal,_G67=weak,_G76=yes]
[_G40=rain,_G49=mild,_G58=high,_G67=strong,_G76=no]
```

but I have this result. Why? Do you have any ideas about this?

Answer (score 4):

The predicate could look like:

```
   merge([], [], []).
   merge([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], [X=Y|Zs]) :- merge(Xs, Ys, Zs).
```

You start with the base case of empty list and induct by case of two lists with the same length.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I want to this. But there is a problem start:- consult('tennis.pl'),
  see('tennis.pl'),
  repeat,
  read(A),
  A=..List,
  (A\=end_of_file->
  (A\=end_of_file,member('attributes',List)->
  delete(List,'attributes',YeniList2);true),
  (A\=end_of_file,member('data',List)->
  delete(List,'data',YeniList);true),
  merge(YeniList2,YeniList,Dene),
  write(Dene),nl;true),
  A=end_of_file,!,
 
  seen.

Comment: You should open another question and put the content of tennis.pl into that question too.

Answer (score 2):

No problem with [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`maplist/4`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/4609915) together with 
[lambda expressions](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord):

```
?- use_module(library(lambda)).
true.

?- maplist(\K^V^(K=V)^true, [a,b,c], [1,2,3], KVs).
KVs = [a=1, b=2, c=3].
```